# Mouse Suddenly Stops working or loses functionality & becomes oversensitive

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad

I've had a Dell Inspiron Laptop for a bit.  Occasionally the touchpad will stop working correctly.  I notice this happens if the following happens:

1. Randomly
2. If a small object lands in the touchpad when moving across the x and/or y axis on the touchpad w/ a finger.

Attempted "[grug](https://grugbrain.dev/)" resolution:

For a bit, I was able to disable the device in xinput, re-enable it with a 20% success rate.  This has now dropped to 0%.  Me no know y?

Observations:

1. running `diff` on the output of `xinput list-props 12` against the working then non-working status of the touchpad yields no differences.  diff of `gsettings ...touchpad --list-recursive` is also not different between working and messed up.
2. Rarely the input is completely removed from xinput and all control is lost, requires shutdown walk outside and then restart.
3. Natural Scrolling is disabled, scrolling on the touchpad is disabled, the sensitivity are increased to the max.

### Are there any other ways I can log what is happening w/ my touchpad?

OTHER WAYS FOUND: `libinput debug-events --verbose`

- When the it stop responding.  this catpures no input
- tbd: what happens when it stops scrolling / etc

Comment: It could well be a hardware problem. I'd start with a live distribution, just to have a different environment. If the issue persists you might have to give up on that mouse.